# Question on definition of a continuous function using example

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a question on the definition of a continuous function.  I provide some definitions, an example and questions.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) says sufficiently small changes in input of a continuous function result in small changes in output and that Cauchy defined continuity of $y = f(x)$ per above as $f(x + \alpha) - f(x)$ over all values.  Then Weierstrass defined it using $(\epsilon, \delta)$ ranges.  Finally, the function is continuous at some point $c$ of its domain if $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$

My question is application of these definitions to the following example.  Let $f(c)$ be the first point on the right closed interval.

[image: rightc]

It's my understanding this function is discontinuous at $c$.  Applying the Cauchy definition to the image: $c \in \mathbb{R}$ approaches from the left there is no change in the output, therefore the function is discontinuous.  Is this correct analysis?  I get confused because $f(c)$ **is** a change in output from the left side of the function.

Similarly applying $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$ one finds $f(x) \neq f(c)$ also showing discontinuity at $f(c)$.

Finally applying $(\epsilon, \delta)$ to above, $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c) \iff (0 \lt |x - c| \lt \delta) \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon)$.  In this case I'm assuming the inequalities are false?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the discontinuity is at $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's say that earlier $f(x)$ takes value $1$ and after $c$ it takes value $2$.

Taking them one by one:

**Cauchy's definition:** This is the definition that a small change in $x$ gives a small change in $f(x)$. At $c$ above, no matter how small you change $x$ around $c$, $f(x)$ is gonna jump by $2-1$ units. Meaning you can't ever achieve a smaller change than $1$ unit. No matter how small you "wiggle" $x$ around $c$, $f(x)$ will always wiggle at least $1$ unit around $f(c)$. The idea of continuity is that you should always be able to make the wiggling of $f$ as small as you'd like (by making the wiggling of $x$ small enough).

**Limit definition:** You seem to have gotten this one.

**$\epsilon-\delta$ definition:** If for instance, I take $\epsilon = 0.5$, then no matter how small I take $\delta$, for every point $x \in (c - \delta, c)$, $|f(c) - f(x)| = |2-1| = 1 > \epsilon = 0.5$.

Of course all three definitions ultimately prove discontinuity by basically the same means, which is to be expected as they are equivalent.

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is defined sufficiently large (above $\ge 1$), it seems the function we are discussing will be continuous.  So how is $\epsilon$ defined?  Also, am I correct saying the above function is continuous at $c$ approaching from values $x \ge c$ and discontinous approaching from values $x \le c$?  Thanks